¿Cómo puedo pasar un argumento a un controlador desde un componente de Blazor?
Tengo una aplicacion Blazor WASM y quiero pasar el argumento int numreg = 3 desde el componente Productos.razor al controlador ProductosController.
El problema es que no envía el valor 3. Mi código es como sigue:
@code {
    public IEnumerable<Producto> Productos { get; set; } = new List<Producto>();

    // Para la parte de borrar
    private bool estaProcesando { get; set; } = false;
    private int? BorrarIdProducto { get; set; } = null;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Productos = await productosServicio.GetProductos(3);
    }
}

Y en el controlador:
  [AllowAnonymous]
  [HttpGet]
  [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden)]
  [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
  public IActionResult GetProductos(int numreg)
  {
      var listaProductos = _productoRepo.GetProductos(numreg);
      var listaProductosDTO = new List<ProductoDTO>();
      foreach (var item in listaProductos)
      {
          listaProductosDTO.Add(_mapper.Map<ProductoDTO>(item));
      }
      return Ok(listaProductosDTO);
  }

En el controlador, numreg es 0 en vez de 3.
Qué estoy haciendo mal?
Edito:
El código que tengo en la clase ProductoServicio es el siguiente:
using ClienteBlazorWASM.Helpers;
using ClienteBlazorWASM.Modelos;
using ClienteBlazorWASM.Servicios.IServicio;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json.Nodes;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClienteBlazorWASM.Servicios
{
    public class ProductosServicio : IProductosServicio
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _cliente;

        public ProductosServicio(HttpClient cliente)
        {
            _cliente = cliente;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Producto>> GetProductos(int numreg)
        {
            // response o respuesta
            var response = await _cliente.GetAsync($"{Inicializar.UrlBaseApi}api/productos");
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var productos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Producto>>(content);
            return productos;
        }
    }
}


Hace un tiempo que no toco Blazor, y podría estar equivocado. Pero tengo entendido que para pasar argumentos desde un componente a un controlador necesitarías hacer una petición GET con HttpClient. Porque tu componente se ejecuta en el lado del cliente y tu controlador en el lado del servidor.

Gtacias Hector por tu respuesta. La verdad es que soy nuevo en esto. Si no es mucha molestia, podrás mandarme un pequeño ejemplo de lo que mencionas? Muchas gracias de antemano. Saludos

Primero, necesito que me aclares algunas cosas. Puedes Editar tu pregunta y mostrar como tienes configurado tu productosServicio. Es decir, el código que tienes dentro de la clase ProductoServicio que inyectas a tu componente.

Listo Hector. Acabo de copiar lo solicitado, en la edicion de mi preguna (al final, como PD). No sé si necesites algo más. Gracias

Muchas gracias Mario. Y creo que ya veo el problema. En ningún momento usas el argumento entero numreg cuando haces la petición GET. Debería ser _cliente.GetAsync($"{Inicializar.UrlBaseApi}api/productos?numreg={numreg}"); y en el controlador, deberías poner public IActionResult GetProductos([FromQuery] int numreg).

El atributo [FromQuery] indica que el controlador obtendrá el valor del argumento numreg de la lista de argumentos precedidos por ? en la URL de la petición.

Excelente Hector. Me funcionó a la perfección!  Mil gracias. Saludos!

Me alegra que te haya servido. He dejado la solución en forma de respuesta para futuros lectores. Si gustas, puedes marcarla como respuesta y votarla según consideres. Un saludo.

Dejo esta respuesta para futuros lectores.
El problema que experimentas, es porque en tu clase ProductoServicio olvidaste hacer uso del argumento numreg.
Al momento de hacer la petición GET debes pasar el valor del argumento a tu URL:
public class ProductosServicio : IProductosServicio
{
    private readonly HttpClient _cliente;

    public ProductosServicio(HttpClient cliente)
    {
        _cliente = cliente;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Producto>> GetProductos(int numreg)
    {
        var response  = await _cliente.GetAsync($"{Inicializar.UrlBaseApi}api/productos?numreg={numreg}");
        var content   = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var productos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Producto>>(content);

        return productos;
    }
}

Una vez hecho esto, el método de tu controlador necesita el atributo [FromQuery], de esta forma:
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public IActionResult GetProductos([FromQuery] int numreg)
{
    var listaProductos    = _productoRepo.GetProductos(numreg);
    var listaProductosDTO = new List<ProductoDTO>();

    foreach (var item in listaProductos)
    {
        listaProductosDTO.Add(_mapper.Map<ProductoDTO>(item));
    }

     return Ok(listaProductosDTO);
}

El atributo [FromQuery] le indica al método de tu controlador que, obtendrá el valor del argumento desde los argumentos proporcionados a la URL, precedidos por ?.
